# Graphics.drawString() doesnt draw anything on the screen

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, draw

I'm trying to draw a string with the `Graphics.drawString()`. But for some reason nothing shows up on the screen. Drawing a rectangle for example works but `drawString()` doesn't.

Here's my code:

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        this.setSize(350, 500);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
    
        //Nothing is drawn on the screen.
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 25));
        g.drawString("Hello", 10, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's usually better to override `paintComponent` on a JPanel and add the panel to the frame. Also you might want to move down the string, because currently it will be off the top of the frame.

Comment: Change `g.drawString("Hello", 10, 10);` to `g.drawString("Hello", 10, 40);` & the problem might start to make sense..

Answer (score 1):

When using `Graphics` class to draw anything to the `Component`, you should know one important thing:

While `drawRect(int x, int y, int width, int height)` method the `x` and `y` are the **top-left** corner, in the `drawString(String s, int x, int y)` the `x` and `y` are the **bottom-left** corner.

In addition, when you draw anything in a `JFrame`, the position start on the top-left corner on the title of the `JFrame`, so the first paintable pixel is in point (~8,
~28), this is different in every operating-system.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of drawing on the JFrame, which is does not draw it to the exact coordinates, make your main class a child of JPanel by using this code:

```
public class Main extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
    
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    
    public Main() {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(this);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(350, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Now add your `paint` method

```
@Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
    
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 25));
        g.drawString("Hello", 10, 10);
    }
```